# Where is Experience Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

I'm looking for "Experience Stack Exchange" or probably "Personal Experience Stack Exchange" site (I can't recall the exact name) but can't find it.

I used to visit it few years ago or so.

On that site people used to ask questions about all type of personal experiences including but not limited to: love, relationship, marriage etc, and I'm not talking about "User Experience Stack Exchange".

Any idea what happened to it?

Comment: Why downvote ??

Comment: This not duplicate question. Its not about Interpersonal Stack Exchange.

Comment: You need to be more specific then. Based on what you've presented so far only IPS.se does qualify and no other site existed that looked similar to that. Contenders could be: https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic or https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic or even https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/ but all those site have evolved in what they consider on-topic. Maybe the type of questions you do expect have been cleared out to make room for a better focus.

Comment: Maybe [Personal Productivity](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4296/personal-productivity) but that didn't survive.

Comment: @rene To be more specific and explicit, I used to visit that site when I was in puberty stage. There I used to read questions like "How did you ejaculated first time?" or "How does sex feel like?" but also like "How did you fall in love?". It was almost 5 years ago when I visited it last time.

Comment: Ah, I think you may be talking about the [Sexuality](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62814/sexuality) site. That was later shut down as it failed in private beta. There was a [prior attempt](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3303/sexuality) at establishing such a site, but it failed as well.

Comment: There was also an [old attempt](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44577/relationships-and-dating) at establishing a relationships and dating site, but it was shut down in private beta as well. The current Interpersonal Skills site is the only one of the bunch that survived private beta, and is currently in public beta.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the [Interpersonal Skills Beta site](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It was not Interpersonal Stack Exchange. People there ask questions about all type of personal experiences not interpersonal skills. I can't recall the exact name but I'm sure it was Stack Exchange site and it had word Experience in its name.

Comment: To avoid some confusion and a flood of off-topic sex/relationship questions: **Interpersonal Skills are behaviours used to interact with people and achieve certain goals.** While we do require questions to provide us with what was experienced so far and a goal to reach, and answers to be based on experience as well, we're not as general a site that *all type of personal experiences including but not limited to: love, relationship, marriage* is by definition on-topic. They may be mentioned, but they're not our real focus.